# Dúvida em recursão com String em Java

Tags: java, string, recursão

Estou tentando resolver o seguinte exercício:

> Uma coleção S de cadeias de caracteres é definida recursivamente por:
>
> - 'a' e 'b' pertencem a S;
> - se X pertence a S, então Xb também pertence a S;
>
> Escreva um procedimento que implemente essa definição recursivamente e diga quais das seguintes cadeias pertencem a S:
>
> (a) a
>
> (b) ab
>
> (c) aba
>
> (d) aaab
>
> (e) bbbbb

O meu código está da seguinte forma:

```
    static boolean funcao(String str){
        if(str.equals("a") || str.equals("b"))
             return true;
        return(...)
```

No último `return` é onde não consigo resolver, eu sei que na teoria ele deveria estar mais ou menos assim:

```
   retorna(str[ultimo caracter] == 'b' && funcao(str[do primeiro ao penúltimo caractere]);
```

Porém não estou conseguindo, alguém saberia me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> str[ultimo caracter]
> ```

```
str.charAt(str.length() - 1)
```

> ```
> str[do primeiro ao penúltimo caractere]
> ```

```
str.substring(0, str.length() - 1)
```

Mas ainda falta uma condição para funcionar, pois você tem que garantir que exista ao menos um caractere na string. Isso é possível com um `if (str.isEmpty()) return false;`. Você também pode aproveitar esse `if` e verificar o caso da string ser `null`.

O código fica assim:

```
private static boolean funcao(String str) {
    if (str == null || str.isEmpty()) return false;
    if (str.equals("a") || str.equals("b")) return true;
    return str.charAt(str.length() - 1) == 'b'
            && funcao(str.substring(0, str.length() - 1));
}
```